# How to use the new types of strings in Delphi Xe2?

Tags: string, delphi, dll

*Please note, sarnold has heavily edited the question; the original
question, in its entirety, is kept in the question as a comment. If I made
something unclear, perhaps the original post will be helpful. (I'm leaving
it as a comment so future editors do not need to always refer to the
question edit history.)*

I'm working with Delphi Xe2 and need help understanding how to use ANSI
strings, Unicode strings, and Wide-character strings, correctly,
especially when writing a DLL intended for use with other languages (such
as VB, C++, or C#).

I need to write a DLL using Delphi Xe2 to perform simple string operations
on Unicode strings. This DLL needs to work **with one is `SimpleShareMem` or
`ShareMem` or without** memory managers. This DLL needs to be callable from foreign
languages such as VB, C++, and C#.

By default, strings should now be Unicode strings. Should we use
Embarcadero to work with these strings?

Strings are either: (a) single-byte characters that do not support Unicode
or (b) wide strings, where each character requires two bytes. (These do
support Unicode, but they are not UTF-8 strings.)

There are two pointer types available: `PAnsiChar` and `PWideChar` (there
is no `PUnicodeChar` pointer available). `PChar` is an alias for
`PWideChar` -- does this means we always need to allocate `2 * length`
amount of memory for these strings? (And, similarly, do we need to divide
the memory by `2` to get the length of these strings?)

For string constants, do we need to mark the type of the string in the
source code? E.g.:

```
Const MyCo = 'test';
```

or

```
Const MyCo = WideString('test');
```

How about when we perform assignments between string variables?

```
s := st;
```

Should this be re-written:

```
s := WideString(st);
```

Should we include the Unicode Byte Order mark in our strings? How should
we include the BOM in our strings?

How should we work with ANSI strings in different Windows Code Pages? If
we receive an ANSI string with code page 1200, should we re-code the
string or work with it as-is?

How should we use the `TEncoding` class to convert between Unicode, UTF-8,
WideString, and AnsiString classes?

Are there any severe performance penalties using wide strings or Unicode
strings?

Should we write our interfaces to require working with only the WideString
variants when using the general memory manager?

Should we write our interfaces to require length parameters for `PChar`,
`PAnsiChar`, and `PWideChar` parameter types?

How do write our interfaces to determine if a file is stored in Unicode,
UTF-8, ANSI, or Wide Characters? How should we determine what format to
use when writing files back out?

Should we use only procedures? Or can functions work too?

Thanks, and happy new year.

Comment: _BO?_ should be [Byte Order Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). I'd like to suggest asking fewer questions in a Stack Overflow question -- there is a _lot_ here, but I _think_ it comes down to a few small questions: _What type of string should I use for internationalized and localized programs?_ and _How should I use those strings when inter-operating with other programs on the system?_ -- but I'm not confident enough to edit your question. (Sorry.) (Oh yes, Happy new year to you too. :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!
BOM! :) You are right (I remember that began on "BO").
Lines, I simply am afraid to lose a question thread (and I think, that so for others searching too it will be better) if I will set so much separate small, I have tried here, on as much as possible to write them short, I very much would not like to divide all it. If it is possible - correct at least a part of questions which have understood, I will ask friends that the rest have completed. How many at me time (taking into account holidays) that the question has hung without editing any time?

Comment: ++ Still the request - do not put to me minuses, it is very heavy to me to communicate in English, but I try. Minuses here on how many I understand put to spamers and ect, it would not be desirable that the reputation on a site suffered. It is grateful to those who corrects my questions.

Comment: The question cannot be salvaged in my view. Ask a single question.

Comment: Spare me! At me at a forum to me cannot answer, because at many it is still established Delphi 7 :(
Please, can clean a part of questions (though here has tried to describe minimum all), only do not divide into separate questions, differently I will get confused.

Comment: @David: I know what you mean, but I have a feeling that the _answer_ will be simpler than the question: Gu. appears to be asking what is best practices for handling "new" strings provided by a new environment, and that really doesn't sound _horrible_. The portions of the question dealing with the Delphi memory management seriously confused my efforts at re-writing the question, but hopefully someone who is more familiar with Delphi will know what is meant...

Comment: :) Thanks for editing. Many thanks. To begin with though these basic questions.

If it helps, the question original here: (Russian) http://www.delphimaster.ru/cgi-bin/forum.pl?id=1325371999&n=18 
I understand, that I have 2 days on question editing. If editing is not - that it is possible to send the given variant of editing.

Comment: You are almost right. I correctly understand, what I have 2 days on editing? I will write the small program and I will present here its initial code (it is possible?) There all becomes much more clear. Interests not only opinion of Delphi-programmers (to the program) but also VB \C. While I will try to have a sleep and wait for the friend with transfer (at us NEW YEAR of 6 hours as has passed) :)

Comment: Excuse that problems with language, but here so well answer, and at me the question - which holds my big working out, should set it here, editors of the text very help, good luck - "good affairs always = kindly + 1" will be it in new year.

Comment: You should read some book and the come back with remaining question.

Comment: Do not become angry, but some books leave in English. Certainly, it is my problems, forgive me for it.

Comment: Gu, this website is set up in such a way that you'll get the best answers if you ask short, concise questions. Better split this up. That way people can skip questions that somebody else already answered thoroughly, and you'll probably get multiple answers if multple views are possible. Also, people can get a bigger reward for answering multiple questions.  I don't think many people will answer all of your questions as it is now.

Comment: Ok.2 days. If is not present - publish that now is or erase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get the impression that Gu is moving from Delphi 7 to a Unicode enabled version (D2009+) and is looking for advice on how to deal with the new strings.

Cary Jensen's white paper [Delphi Unicode Migration for Mere Mortals](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/40307), addresses most if not all of the issues raised in the question.

*I would normally have put this in a comment, but the list of comments is already so long I felt the link (which may help more people than just Gu) would more easily be found in an answer.*

Answer (score 1):

- ShareMem and SimpleShareMem are usable to share DLLs using strings parameters only among Delphi applications which use the same units. They ensure both the application and the DLL use the same memory manager. You can't them outside Delphi, because VB, C++ and C# will each use their own memory manager. Delphi string types memory layout is compatible with other languages (and viceversa), but strings must be allocated and deallocated using the same memory manager.
- Delphi unicode strings are UTF-16 strings because this is the "native" Windows string type. It can support several 8-bit encodings, including UTF-8, with its AnsiString type.
- UTF-16 doesn't **always** use 2 byte per "character". Some "characters" may use 4 bytes, although these usually appears only if you're doing some "exotic" text processing (musical symbols, dead languages, etc.)
- Converting strings to Unicode is lossless. Otherwise you have to ensure each AnsiString is using the correct codepage to avoid conversion loss. Be aware that many routines go through Unicode conversions, thereby it may be better to convert any non-Unicode string to Unicode and maybe convert back as the final operation (if no encoding-specific processing needs to be performed)
- Because Unicode strings are the default type both in Delphi and Windows, performance should be better because no conversion back and forth are required. Custom code working on UTF-16 strings may be slower, though, due to the more complex handling (UTF-8 may be even more complex, though, as some MBCS encodings).
- A BOM is usually used in text files, not for in-memory strings. Data from outside should be converted into the native in-memory format when read/received. Otherwise a conversion to the native format would be required whenever the string is passed to a function which expects it. The ouput form is up to your application, you need to have code that can dtermine it or ask the user.

Answer (score -1):

AS, you'd better put those question in rsdn.ru forum, I feel they are more liberal to novices than DelphiMasters.

Gu, basically, you should just read manuals in Delphi XE2. It's all there, just read with thinking and attention.

1) you should NOT make DLL at all. You should make BPL.
DLL is intended to co-operate with plain C interface like Win32 API.
Those are most primitive types without any side-effects.
C is called "machine-independent" assembler for its primitivity, and DLL interface is a kind of it.

DLL may be used for compatibility with another languages, because they use another side-effects incompatible with Delphi. Then DLL enforces most primitive co-operation, with all side-effects removed from interface. By lowering intercommunication level to most simplistic types, DLL interface enforces the compatibility.

But when you need to interact Delphi to Delphi then you'd better allow Delphi to care about all compatibility issues. that is what BPL made for in Delphi 3.
There is just no reasons to use DLLs for this.

Of course, you may shoot yourself in the foot, if u like to.
https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?threadID=64114

2) You should not use WideString in XE2 but a UnicodeString instead.
Manual on strings is especially highlighting this. So it seems you just did not read manual.

3) string constants are in Unicode. (but char constants are in... in ANSI or in Unicode randomly, which leads to unexpected behaviour bugs).
And there's no need to ask and trust anyone's words - just open your exe in any viewer and search for those constants, you would find them in 2-bytes UCS-2 (aka WideChar) encoding.

4) Unicode BOM is used to determine CPU byte order, is it Intel or Motorola fashion.
When you develop for Windows you can only have Intel byte order, so no need to BOM.

5) the whole paragraph you wrote about lengths and memory sizes is very ambiguous. What do you mean by length, in which units it is measured, where do you take it from?

I assume that by length you meant count of characters not including any "behind the hood" service structures/characters. That is what built-in function System.Length(string or array) returns.
However if this assumption is wrong, then the answer below becomes wrong too.

And the question if you should multiply by 2 is just a sign of bad code.
You should always multiply by something, years ago you already should multiply.
Multiply by... what? By SizeOf(char-variable used) or SizeOf(char-type used).
Then t would be Delphi that would automatically determine how much memory needed.
And dealing with C-string you should use not length, but length+1 - don't forget about #0 terminator.

6) *How should we work with ANSI strings in different Windows Code Pages? If we receive an ANSI string with code page 1200, should we re-code the string or work with it as-is?*

RTFM !!!
Just declare type AnsiString with code page 1200.
or use RawByteStrnig and SetCodePage.
Read the real code below.

Again, RTFM - that ALL is described in built-in help.
It only takes 2 hours to read it ALL in built-in help of Delphi XE2.

7) *how should we use the TEncoding class to convert between Unicode, UTF-8, WideString, and AnsiString classes?* TEncoding is made for TStringList or something like that.
Why should you? There is UTF8String type - just use it.

var as: AnsiString; ucs2s: string; utf8string: UTF8String;
... as := ucs2; utf8s := as; ....

8) *Are there any severe performance penalties using wide strings or Unicode strings?*
That is depending upon which "Unicode" you mean, UCS-2 or UTF8. And which operations do you want to use.
Just make a looong loop and measure the time.

9) *Should we write our interfaces to require length parameters for PChar, PAnsiChar, and PWideChar parameter types?*
That is you choice, do as you wish.
Usually PChar is C-string ended with #0. And this is how StrLen function works.
If you ignore that convention and use it like untypes Pointer - then pass length separately.

ALL those question are already answered in help!!! Just read it.

---

```
function CDF_File_Buffer.GetStringNoBounds(const ofs, len: integer): string;
// Распознать кодировку, не проверять адреса
var cntDOS, cntWin, cntWeird, i : Cardinal;
    sBuf: RawByteString; cp: word;
    ptr, ptr_i: PAnsiChar;
const rusDOS: set of AnsiChar = [#$80..#$AF, #$E0..#$F1];
      rusWin: set of AnsiChar = [#$C0..#$FF];
begin
   ptr := Pointer(Header);  Inc(ptr, ofs);

   case textCharset of
     tcsGuess:
       begin
           ptr_i := ptr;  cntDOS :=0; cntWin :=0; cntWeird:=0;
           for i := 1 to len do begin
               if ptr_i^ in rusDOS then Inc(cntDOS);
               if ptr_i^ in rusWin then Inc(cntWin);
               if (ptr_i^ < #32) or ((ptr_i^ >= #127) and not(ptr_i^ in rusWin) and not(ptr_i^ in rusDOS))
                   then inc(cntWeird);

               Inc(ptr_i);
           end;
           if (cntWin > cntDOS) or (cntWeird > cntDOS) then cp := 1251 else cp := 866;
       end;
     tcsWin: cp := 1251;
     tcsDOS: cp := 866;
     else cp := 0; // быть не должно такого
   end;

   SetString(sBuf,ptr,len); 

   for i := 1 to Length(sBuf) do  if sBuf[i] = #0 then sBuf[i] := #7;
   // Не совсем корректно заменять нули, но
   // 1) неизвестно, что вообще в этом поле может быть
   // 2) файлы создаются в программе на C++, где нулей в строках не может быть
   // 3) семантику надо выводить на экран, а Windows написана на C++

   SetCodePage(sBuf, cp, false);

   Result := string(sBuf);
end;

function CDF_File_Buffer.GetString(const ofs, len: integer; const min, max: integer): string;
begin
  if (ofs <= 0) or (len <= 0) then
     Exit( '--- нет текста ---');

  if Cardinal(ofs + (len-1)) >= TotalSize then //меньше нуля уже не будет, убираем Warning
     Exit('--- За пределами файла ---');

  Result := '--- За пределами допустимой области: слишком близко к ';
  if ofs < min then Exit(Result + 'началу ---');
  if ofs + (len-1) > max then Exit(Result + 'концу ---');

  Result := GetStringNoBounds(ofs, len);
end;

function CDF_File_Buffer.GetString(const ofs, len: integer): string;
begin
  Result := GetString(ofs, len, 0, TotalSize-1);
end;
```